# I had got runtime error but I can not fix it

Tags: runtime

> ! the problem you find haer:
> https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/smart-bangladesh-day-2023-computer-programming/challenges/help-mike

Harvey Specter has agreed to take Mike Ross to a meeting filled with brilliant scientists at NSA Headquarters. But, as always, it's not going to be easy for Mike. He has to solve a puzzle given by Harvey.

Harvey gives two numbers N and K and defines a set A.

A = { x : x is a natural number ≤ N }
(i.e), A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,...., N}

Mike has to find the total number of pairs of elements A[i] and A[j] belonging to the given set, such that, i < j and their sum is divisible by K

Input Format
An integer T followed by T lines, each containing a pair of space separated integers N and K.

Output Format
T integers on separate lines. Each integer denotes the answer corresponding to that test case.

Constraints

```
1\<=T\<=100
K\<=N\<=109
1\<=K\<=10000
```

Input:

```
2
10 4
7 3
```

Output:

```
10
7
```

Explanation

For the 1st test case, there are 10 pairs whose sum is divisible by 4.
(1,3), (1,7), (2,6), (2,10), (3,5), (3,9), (4,8), (5,7), (6,10) and (7,9)

For the 2nd test case, there are 7 pairs whose sum is divisible by 3.
(1,2), (1,5), (2,4), (2,7), (3,6), (4,5) and (5,7)

I write this solution for the probllem but it's gives me runtime error, I can not fix it can you help me??

```
void test_case()
{

    ll n, k;
    cin \>\> n \>\> k;

    ll mx_sum = n + n;
    vector<ll> v;

    ll i = k;
    while (i <= mx_sum)
    {
        v.push_back(i);
        i += k;
    }

    ll ans = 0, temp;
    for (ll i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        if (v[i] <= n)
        {
            temp = v[i] - 1;
            ans += (temp / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            temp = n - (v[i] - n) + 1;
            ans += (temp / 2);
        }
    }

    cout << ans << "\n";

}
```